# Where To Detect Swipes?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-gesture

I have an Activity, a ViewPager (I know this is getting depreciated but it's what I have for now), and a Fragment.  I need to know which of these to hook a GestureDetector.OnGestureListener to for best results.

Also: Does this approach appear standard?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Answer depends on what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use the following method of view pager....

```
vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d("Your position is ", ">"+ position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    });
```

in the onPageSelected() you cn get the current position, on which position you are. Hope this will help you.